# to transfer to or for transfer to

Tags: adverbs

Which of these examples is correct?

As she prepares for her transfer to a new academy to pursue her formation

**or**

As she prepares to transfer to a new academy to pursue her formation

Comment: You can either *prepare **for** [noun]*, or you *prepare **to** [verb]*. So you're free to choose either of your example forms.

Comment: Both correct, but the one with *for* avoids the repetition in "**to** transfer **to**."

Comment: Both correct, but the one with _for_ avoids the repetition in '**to** transfer **to** a new academy **to**'. But what on earth does '[to] pursue one's formation' mean? 'To complete her education', 'to further her academic career', or 'in pursuit of her dream' are idiomatic.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - So what's wrong with a to-to train?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth in french, the word **formation** means **training**: i am guessing that that's the intended meaning. The usage of the word **academy** also gives a french sound to the sentence. I would be interested to know the source of the quote.

Comment: @JavaLatte Merci, but 'to pursue her formation' makes both sentences incorrect, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I would say quirky, rather than incorrect. I can imagine a Canadian french speaker saying it in English. Anyway, that's not the part that the question is about.

Comment: @JavaLatte (2) The title question licenses such comment, and ELU's brief is to address correct usage. (1) In my opinion, unacceptable according to Orwell's Sixth Law. Beyond quirky.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you probably mean Orwell's fifth rule.  The sixth sounds like more fun, though: "6. Break any of these rules sooner than say anything outright barbarous." The OP does not quote the source of the sentence: without knowing that, it is impossible to say whether or not its use is legitimate in this context. Did you know, for example, that the training of priests is still referred to as **formation**?

Comment: @JavaLatte No; it would take a long debate to get close to deciding whether the '**if** you can think of an everyday English equivalent' applies here. OP could well be doing their best. But Orwell's Sixth can be generalised to 'Avoid the barbarous at all costs [unless you're aiming to sound outlandish]'. this entails 'grammaticality isn't everything, and is sometimes sacrificed for the greater good; it's certainly not the sole factor deciding acceptability'.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. **transfer** can be a noun or a verb, and this affects how it is used.

In the first sentence, **transfer** is a noun. You can tell that because it's preceded by the possessive determiner **her**. Because it's a noun, the preposition **for** is required. Here is another noun example:

> You need a mental break and you need more time to prepare **for the transition** between the two exam styles. - *How to prepare for the medical boards - Adeleke T Adesina*

In the second sentence, **transfer** is a verb, and so, after prepare, it must be preceded by an infinitive marker **to**. Here is another verb example:

> How does a person prepare **to become** a leader? - *the 360 degree leader - John C Maxwell*

Answer (score -1):

Both are correct.

In the first sentence 'transfer' works as a noun. In the second sentence 'transfer' functions as a verb.

Prepare for (+ noun)- ... prepares for her transfer.../ prepares for a transfer

prepare to (+ verb)- ... prepares to transfer...